# imabsdiff() in Python - different output

Tags: python, matlab

i want to use the function **imabsdiff()** from matlab in python, but the output is different.

Matlab:

```
I  = imread('1968.png')
I2 = imread('1971.png')
Z = imabsdiff(I2,I)
imshow(Z)
```

Python:

```
I  = cv2.imread("1968.png",0)
I  = cv2.normalize(I, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
I1 = cv2.imread("1971.png",0)
I1  = cv2.normalize(I1, None, alpha=0, beta=1, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)

aa = abs(Ib-Ic)
cv2.imshow("WW",aa.reshape(32,32))
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Why are the outputs different? What does imabsdiff() from matlab exactly do?

Comment: Have you read the help of `imabsdiff` ? Have you taken the time to compare `abs(Ib-Ic)` in matlab with the output of this function? Have you taken the time to check what kind of input `I2` and `I` are? This has nothing to do with python, take your time to debug things yourself and to understand what you are doing

Comment: The problem was not the function! I plot the diff image wrong. After I use matplotlib, i saw the same output.